# Am I safe to install Wine?

Tags: release-freya, wine

I want to install wine on my elementaryOS Freya system.  It marks two packages for removal - `xdg-user-dirs` and `xdg-user-dirs-gtk`, which I'm hesitant to approve.  Are these packages essential/will I break my system by going ahead with the installation?  If so, is there a work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed WINE on my system using the `ubuntu-wine` PPA (personal package archive) because the software center WINE would not install and had no problems with it on my system which is freya 0.3.2 64-bit.

#### To add the PPA and install WINE run the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.8
```

You should now have a perfectly working WINE installation. If you have any problems add a comment to this answer

Comment: this one? ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa

Comment: @TimothyGray Yes

Comment: and did you get the same conflicts I am?

Comment: @TimothyGray Don't remember

Answer (score -1):

I've been using it on and off without installing any additional ppa's for awhile and I haven't noticed any issues.

Comment: The PPA is more up to date

Comment: Your not even giving instructions how to install WINE